# Best way to move records in sorted-by-column table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting

I'm facing a problem to create a function for moving up / down records in MySQL database. My current table looks like:

```
Id UNSIGNED INT AI PRIMARY | Some other columns | Sort UNSIGNED INT INDEX
```

Let's say I've got some data:

```
1 | FirstRecord | 1
2 | Second | 2
3 | Third | 3
4 | 4th | 4
Much more data...
```

After action 'Move Up' on 'Id = 4' I want 'Id = 4' to get 'Sort' of 'Id @above' and 'Id @above' to get 'Sort' of 'Id = 4'

**What I have on the begginig:**

- Id of record I want to move
- The direction I want to move (up / down)

**What I want to have in the end**

- My record moved up or down (swapped 'Sort' values)
- Consecutive numbers in 'Sort' column

**How I want to do it**

- Because I'm using php5.4 I can use some code in this language, not only pure sql
- I must be prepared for high load and simultaneous requests
- I don't want to create MySQL procedures or functions. The best way will be do do it in one simple query

**What I've tried**

- The simplest way was to use php and:

  - Get 'Sort' of current Id (1st query)
  - Find Id of column above / below (2nd query)
  - Get 'Sort' of this column (3rd query)
  - Swap 'Sort' values (4th and 5th query)

**Pros** are that this method is quite simple, and i think thats all.

**Cons** are that for a moment both rows have the same 'Sort' value. Another is that when 2 scripts runs in the same time, the result may be unpredicted. Also after deleting any record, there would be a hole in numeration.

- More complicated, also using php

  - Change 'Sort' to FLOAT (at the beggining, not every time)
  - Substract or Add 1.5 from the record.
  - Update or records in SQL query to make the numbers consecutive

**Pros**: no need to read antything about next / previous record. After each move we are sure, that 'Sort' numbers will be ok. We can use UNIQUE on Sort.

**Cons**: In huge tables it would take lots of CPU time to assign new Sort numbers. Am I right? We also have 'Sort' in different type than Id...

- Similar to previous

  - Substract / Add 1 from / to record we want to move.
  - Assign consecutive numbers by query using our Id as second Sort parameter.

**Pros**: Same as above, but no way to use UNIQUE. But we have 'Sort' in same type as Id

**Cons**: For some time both records have the same 'Sort', high cpu usage (?)

Up to now these are the best methods I know about. Does anybody of you know any other, linking all pros and not having cons?

Thanks for your replays.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need 1 query for the record you want to move to get the sort index. Then you should have the new sort index an input from the sort UI.

If you're just swapping two items you can do it in one query:

```
UPDATE table SET sort_index = IF(id === ?id?, ?new_sort_index?, ?old_sort_index?) WHERE id = ?id? OR sort_index = ?new_sort_index?
```

Using the `IF` you update two records at one.

If you can move one item many places you need to do a range update. First figure out the direction: up/down. Then do a query like:

```
UPDATE table SET sort_index = sort_index + 1 WHERE sort_index >= ?new_sort_index? AND sort_index < ?old_sort_index?
```

This created a space at ?new_sort_index? and removed a space at ?old_sort_index?

Then one final query to set the new sort index for the moved record.

The latter approach works if even if your index is sparse (ie. there are holes) the former doesn't, so keep that in mind.